# wcf mtom updating boundary value format

Tags: c#, wcf, mtom

I'm currently stuck with a problem related to the 'boundary' value within the MIME header. We have a wcf service with custom binding to support mtom. Here is a portion of a sample MIME header that we are getting out of our service:

```
content-type: multipart/related; 
type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="uuid:f45e6739-e796-41c7-bc96-6dd977a185f6+id=2";start-info="application/soap+xml"
```

We are using the NIST message validator to validate the soap message along with the MIME header, and the validator is not liking the 'boundary' value for some reason and the validation fails. In the above sample boundary value, if I just take out the '=' sign and make it look like this,

```
boundary="uuid:f45e6739-e796-41c7-bc96-6dd977a185f6+id2"
```

the validation passes. So can you please me in getting rid of this '=' sign from the boundary value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The '=' is a legal value according to [RFC1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html):

```
boundary := 0*69<bchars> bcharsnospace 
bchars := bcharsnospace / " " 
bcharsnospace := DIGIT / ALPHA / "'" / "(" / ")" / "+" / "_" 
                 / "," / "-" / "." / "/" / ":" / "=" / "?"
```

It's apparently NIST's validator that's broken.

Unfortunately I don't believe there is any way to customize the boundary format in WCF.